# xCode 4.6, iPad is it possible to use "old school" spring struts for storyboards instead of constraints?

Tags: ipad, interface, constraints, xcode4.6, autoresizingmask

I've recently had the misfortune to upgrade to xCode 4.6 and notice that as I'm laying out the storyboard for the old <--> |--| springs and struts for views are gone and are replaced by some weird content offsets relative to views. I no longer understand what happens to my views, and would like to use the "old school" springs and struts that I'm used to. Is it possible to force xCode 4.6 to show springs and struts for storyboard/nib files as they were in older xCode?

This is what I would like to see(autoresizing masks):
[image: old springs and struts]

This is what I see instead (constraints):

[image]

Comment: just uncheck the autoLayout from your fileInspector. It will automatically remove constaraints from your xib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just uncheck the `Use autoLayout` from your file Inspector. It will automatically remove constaraints from your xib

select storyboard file, then the first icon in the right panel, the flag is on the bottom of the provided image.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! reading documentation I found that this flag is automatically checked for new storyboards created using iOS6 deployment target

Comment: yes, you need to uncheck if you don't want to use auto layout!
Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 2):

Open the Utilities panel in XCode, select your XIB and click Show File Inspector in Xcode Utilities panel. It is the left most icon along the top. Uncheck "Use Autolayout".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Select the file in navigator then on the right, switch to the file property pane and turn off constraints.